# how to do for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

```
aa <-order(maxstaCode$ gateInComingCnt,decreasing=TRUE)[1:10]
aa
 [1]  11 121  19  79  13  21  43  10  15 138
```

```
for(i in aa){
maxinnum<-c(maxstaCode$gateInComingCnt[i])
}
maxinum
```

I wanted to use the loop to bring the numbers of aa into the index value in the chart in sequence, and runs out of the value corresponding to the index value the result below

```
[1] 6235770 2805043 2772432 2592227 2461369 2428441 1990890 1821025 1595055
[10] 1491299
```

but it turned out:

```
[1] 1491299
```

Comment: You don't need a loop for this, `maxstaCode$gateInComingCnt[aa]` orders the entire vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `for` loop, the issue was that `maxinum` is updated on each iteration, resulting in returning the last value.  Instead we need to use `c(maxinum, ...)`

```
maxinum <- c()
for(i in aa){
   maxinum <- c(maxinum, maxstaCode$gateInComingCnt[i])
}
maxinum
```